# process bar on clicked wont work

Tags: javascript

```
<body align="center">
<progress value="0" max="100" id="p1"></progress>
<form id="form_Warpper" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
                <div class="radio_Warpper">
                <p> 1. </p>
                <label> I am a. </label>
                <div class="allQuestion"><?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){?><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" id="p1" value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$i?> <?php } ?></div>
                </div>

                <div class="radio_Warpper">
                <p> 2. </p>
                <label> I am b. </label>
                <div class="allQuestion"><?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){?><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" id="p2"value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$i?> <?php } ?></div>
                </div><!-- 12 -->

                <div class="radio_Warpper">
                <p> 3. </p>
                <label> I am c. </label>
                <div class="allQuestion"><?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){?><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$i?> <?php } ?></div>
                </div><!-- 13 -->

                <div class="radio_Warpper">
                <p> 4. </p>
                <label> I am d. </label>
                <div class="allQuestion"><?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){?><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$i?> <?php } ?></div>
                </div><!-- 14 -->


                <div class="radio_Warpper">
                <p> 5. </p>
                <label> I am e. </label>
                <div class="allQuestion"><?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){?><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$i?> <?php } ?></div>
                </div><!-- 15 -->

                <div class="radio_Warpper">
                <p> 6. </p>
                <label> I am f. </label>
                <div class="allQuestion"><?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){?><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[2]" value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$i?> <?php } ?></div>
                </div><!-- 16 -->

                <input name="submit" type="submit">Sumbit</input>
              </div>
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function incr() { 
var v1=document.getElementById('p1').value;
document.getElementById("p1").value= v1 + 1;
}
</script>
```

i have having a php page with js function , my intention is to make a progress bar on each question was clicked , so each question can only be clicked once , but if i re-click the radio in same question , the process will increase , i need all question can only be clicked once.

so there is 6 question , will be 1/6 , 2/6 and so on. how i going to make the question radio only be clicked once , and i dont wanted jquery or disable the radio i want them can be re-click again, please have a look.

Comment: You need to keep track of whether that particular question has been clicked before, and don't increment the bar if it has. This will require some additional storage, likely an array of has-clicked flags.

Comment: so i need to build a array and target it one by one ? can you sure me a easy sample? thank for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add **onclick** on each of the radio input and assign an ID to each question:

```
<div class="radio_Warpper">
<p> 1. </p>
<label> I am a. </label>
<div class="allQuestion"><?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){?><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" onclick="incr('a')" id="p1" value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$i?> <?php } ?></div>
</div>
```

Please note that **onclick="incr('a')"** is inserted above in the radio input. As for second question, you can use something like **onclick="incr('b')"**. As for the **incr** function, I recommend you to add this:

```
var memoryPool = new Array();

function incr(id) {

 var found = 0;

 for (var i=0; i<memoryPool.length; i++) {
  if (memoryPool[i] == id) {
   found = 1;
  }
 }
 if (!found) {
  var v1=document.getElementById('p1').value;
  document.getElementById("p1").value= v1 + 10;
  memoryPool.push(id);
 }
}
```

Note that the ID of each question is needed to avoid adding extra progess value if there is a change in the answer. Also note that I increment the progress by 10 to see the progress clearly. In the end, you still need to change the increment value to 1/totalQuestions*100 to reflect the actual percentage change.

Hope this solves your problem!